# equivalent of NASM's "dd" in Gnu Assembler

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to translate `dd` from NASM (or MASM) to GAS.
I can't find it anywhere in the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NASM, the `dd` pseudo op defines a "double word" (e.g. 4 byte integer):

http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-pseudop.html
https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2

```
; Example:
dd      0x12345678          ; 0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12
```

In Gas, the corresponding directive would typically be `.long`:

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Long.html

```
; example:
dimensions:
  .long 0, 0
```